# Opencv Mat vector assignment to a row of a matrix, fastest way?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

What is the fastest way of assigning a vector to a matrix row in a loop? I want to fill a **data matrix** along its rows with vectors. These vectors are computed in a loop. This loop last until all the entries of **data matrix** is filled those vectors.

Currently I am using `cv::Mat::at<>()` method for accessing the elements of the matrix and fill them with the vector, however, it seems this process is quite slow. I have tried another way by using `cv::Mat::X.row(index) = data_vector`, it works fast but fill my matrix `X` with some garbage values which I can not understand, why.

I read that there exists another way of using pointers (fastest way), however, I can not able to understand. Can somebody explain how to use them or other different methods?

Here is a part of my code:

```
#define OFFSET 2

cv::Mat im = cv::imread("001.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Mat X = cv::Mat((im.rows - 2*OFFSET)*(im.cols - 2*OFFSET), 25, CV_64FC1); // Holds the training data. Data contains image patches
cv::Mat patch = cv::Mat(5, 5, im.type()); // Holds a cropped image patch
typedef cv::Vec<float, 25> Vec25f;

int ind = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < (im.rows - 2*OFFSET); row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < (im.cols - 2*OFFSET); col++){

    cv::Mat temp_patch = im(cv::Rect(col, row, 5, 5)); // crop an image patch (5x5) at each pixel
    patch = temp_patch.clone(); // Needs to do this because temp_patch is not continuous in memory 
    patch.convertTo(patch, CV_64FC1);

    Vec25f data_vector = patch.reshape(0, 1); // make it row vector (1X25).
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) 
    {
        X.at<float>(ind, i) = data_vector[i]; // Currently I am using this way (quite slow).
    }

    //X_train.row(ind) = patch.reshape(0, 1); // Tried this but it assigns some garbage values to the data matrix!
    ind += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really want to access a single ROW, it is always continuous afaik.

Answer (score 3):

To do it the regular opencv way you could do :-

```
ImageMat.row(RowIndex) = RowMat.clone();
```

or

```
RowMat.copyTo(ImageMat.row(RowIndex));
```

Haven't tested for correctness or speed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of edits in your code

```
double * xBuffer = X.ptr<double>(0);
for (int row = 0; row < (im.rows - 2*OFFSET); row++){
    for (int col = 0; col < (im.cols - 2*OFFSET); col++){

    cv::Mat temp_patch = im(cv::Rect(col, row, 5, 5)); // crop an image patch (5x5) at each pixel
    patch = temp_patch.clone(); // Needs to do this because temp_patch is not continuous in memory 
    patch.convertTo(patch, CV_64FC1);
    memcpy(xBuffer, patch.data, 25*sizeof(double));
    xBuffer += 25;
    }
}
```

Also, you dont seem to do any computation in patch just extract grey level values, so you can create X with the same type as im, and convert it to double at the end. In this way, you could memcpy each row of your patch, the address in memory beeing `unsigned char* buffer = im.ptr(row) + col

Comment: some things to mention: patch.convertTo(patch,...) will always reallocate memory in each run of the loop. Create another Mat: `cv::Mat convertedPatch;` before the loop and reuse it, memory wont be reallocated. `Clone` isn't necessary if `temp_patch.convertTo(patch,...)` (or convertedPatch) is used directly - not 100% sure if its still continuous then.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/ref/2.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af2d2652e552d7de635988f18a84b53e5):

> if you need to process a whole row of matrix, the most efficient way is to get the pointer to the row first, and then just use plain C operator []:

```
// compute sum of positive matrix elements
// (assuming that M is double-precision matrix)
double sum=0;
for(int i = 0; i < M.rows; i++)
{
    const double* Mi = M.ptr<double>(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < M.cols; j++)
        sum += std::max(Mi[j], 0.);
}
```