# Filling cv::Mat calling function row by row?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this method:

```
//codeSize previously defined
void generateRow(cv::Mat1f &row){
  if(row.cols != codeSize || !row.isContinous() || row.rows!=1)
    return;
  //fill row somehow
}
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
cv::Mat1f mat(rows,cols);
for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
  generateRow(mat.row(i));
```

But I get this error message:

```
../EncoderManager.cpp:100:37: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘cv::Mat1f& {aka cv::Mat_<float>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘cv::Mat_<float>’
```

How can I solve this?

**Possible solution:**

```
for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++){
  cv::Mat1f row(1,cols);
  generateRow(row);
  row.row(1).copyTo(mat.row(i));
}
```

Is this the only solution? If so and if `rows` is big, this is going to be super inefficient!

**Original code:**

The calling method:

```
encoder->encode(imgDesc,code);
```

The method called:

```
void Encoder::encode(cv::Mat1f &descriptors, cv::Mat1f &code){
    if(!checkCode(code) || !checkRows(code,1) || !checkDescriptors(descriptors)){
        throw std::runtime_error("wrong descriptors");
        return;
    }
    encode_(descriptors, code);
}
```

The error:

```
../EncoderManager.cpp: In member function ‘void EncoderManager::GenerateSampledCodes(cv::Mat1f&, int, const string&, const string&, const string&)’:
../EncoderManager.cpp:104:37: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘cv::Mat1f& {aka cv::Mat_<float>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘cv::Mat_<float>’
    encoder->encode(imgDesc,codes.row(i));
                                     ^
In file included from ../EncoderManager.hpp:11:0,
                 from ../EncoderManager.cpp:10:
../Encoder.hpp:21:7: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void Encoder::encode(cv::Mat1f&, cv::Mat1f&)’
  void encode(cv::Mat1f &descriptors, cv::Mat1f &code);
```

Comment: You can pass the pointer or reference to `cv::Mat1f mat` along with row index into `generateRow` to avoid unnecessary copies.

Comment: @alexisrozhkov Could you please write an answer? I'm not sure I understood your solution

Comment: I tried your code and it works correctly for me. Can you post a [mcve]? Where is `code` defined? is it a global variable?

Comment: I'm sorry @Miki, I just posted this small part of code because the rest is very complicated and I don't understand how is it possible that it compiles and works for you..Btw do you agree that we cannot fill the matrix row by row with the code above?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to understand how you _cannot_ fill the matrix, because this should work correctly ;)

Comment: @Miki You mean the Possible Solution or the original code which returns an error? The possible solution involves a copy, which is inefficient

Comment: The original code

Comment: @Miki I don't really understand how's that possible :D I posted the **Original code**  and that's the returned error.  Look at the new section.

Comment: @Miki could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792534/cvmat-memory-is-not-released-even-after-calling-release) question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid overhead due to copies you can pass the allocated matrix inside `generateRow()` and initialize it there (and probably rename it to `initRow()` to make its purpose clearer).

Then your code will probably look like this:

```
void initRow(cv::Mat1f &mat, const size_t rowIdx){
  if(mat.cols != codeSize || !code.isContinous() || mat.rows <= rowIdx)
      return;

  //fill row somehow
}

...

cv::Mat1f mat(rows,cols);

for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
  initRow(mat, i);
```

Comment: I don't understand how this could help. Inside `initRow` a copy would be involved in `//fill row somehow` anyway. Read [this](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4b22e1c23af7a7f2eef8fa478cfa7434) for more

Comment: You probably should provide implementation of `fill row somehow` then, because that seems to be relevant to your question. But the way I see it now it should not necessarily involve copies - you can directly write into `mat` entries without creating a temporary row.

Comment: Using `at<>` and fill directly element by element is incredibly inefficient as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991236/opencv-mat-vector-assignment-to-a-row-of-a-matrix-fastest-way).

Comment: First of all, this is outside the scope of your question, which was filling CV mat row by row. Second - right now you have a choice between allocating a temp row each time and copying or into corresponding row of full matrix, or filling it elementwise the way I suggested. I would be surprised to find out that creating a temp structure would be faster, considering the overhead for allocation.

Comment: If performance is critical in your application you can always work directly with matrix data, but that was _not_ clear from the original question.

Comment: Performance is important. What do you mean by working with matrix data?

Comment: @just using at<> is not _terribly inefficient_. I don't know why you think so, but it's not.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind losing the `cv::Mat1f` interface, you can access the row directly via pointer. This way you don't need to create a `cv::Mat1f` wrapper for your row:

```
void generateRow(float * const row){
  // fill row[0], row[1], etc
}

generateRow(mat.ptr<float>(row_number));
```

Also, did you try calling your original function by `generateRow(cv::Mat1f(mat.row(i)))`? I don't think it copies any data, just create a new header for the row matrix.

Comment: Thanks for yur answer. First, I just migrated everything from `cv::Mat` to `cv::Mat1f`, so no I can't change it back to `cv::Mat` :D In addition, using pointer would loose the whole `Mat` structure which is used in `generateRow`. Finally, if you call `generateRow(cv::Mat1f(mat.row(i)))` I think that you create on the fly an object passed to `generateRow` and `mat.row(i)` is not modified.

Comment: I didn't mention `cv::Mat`. Then, creating the `cv::Mat1f` wrapper is the solution for you, since you create the object your function needs and it doesn't create copies (so the `cv::Mat1f` object that is created on the fly is really an alias of your row).