# cv::Mat memory is not released even after calling release()?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

I've written a method where an image descriptor (like [OpenCV SIFT](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) or [VLFeat Dense SI](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/dsift.html)FT) computes the descriptors for a set of images (save in `std::vector<std::string> files`). The descriptor is called through `ComputeDescriptors(image, descriptorMatrix)` where it fills `descriptorMatrix` with the descriptors computed from.

Then I randomly pick `samples` (usually 50) descriptors and push the `sampledDescriptors` matrix in the returned `std::vector<cv::Mat1f> descriptors`.

This is the code:

```
void SIFTDescriptor::ComputeDescriptorsRange(const std::vector<std::string> &files, std::vector<cv::Mat1f> &descriptors){
    cv::Mat1f imgDescriptors;
    cv::Mat img;
    for(int i=0 ; i<files.size() ; i++){
        std::cout<<"Describing "<<files[i]<<std::endl;
        img = cv::imread(files[i], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        if(!img.data)
            //throw error
        //resoze dim is a class member
        if(resizeDim>0)
            ImgUtility::resize(img,resizeDim);
        ComputeDescriptors(img,imgDescriptors);
        if(samples > 0 && samples < imgDescriptors.rows){
            std::cout<<"Sampling "<<imgDescriptors.rows<<" descriptors..."<<std::endl;
            cv::Mat1f sampledDescripotrs;
            std::vector<int> v(imgDescriptors.rows);
            std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0); //fill v with 0 ... imgDescriptors.rows
            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 g(rd());
            std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
            for(int j=0 ; j<samples; j++){
                sampledDescripotrs.push_back(imgDescriptors.row(v[j]));
            }
            descriptors.push_back(sampledDescripotrs);
            sampledDescripotrs.release();
        }
        else
            descriptors.push_back(imgDescriptors); //copy of a smart pointer, not expensive
        imgDescriptors.release();
        std::cout<<"descriptors["<<i<<"]="<<descriptors[i].rows<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<descriptors[i]<<std::endl;
    }
```

This is done to be memory efficient, especially for dense descriptors such as [VLFeat Dense SIFT](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/dsift.html) where thousands of descriptors are extracted. With thousands of images we would run out of memory in no time. Instead, using this solution, we keep only 50 descriptors per image (which is enough for my training).

However, for some weird reason, there is no big memory usage using OpenCV SIFT, but using VLFeat Dense SIFT the memory grows pretty fast, even if `samples` is equal in both cases!

My only explanation is that the memory used by `imgDescriptors` at each loop is not freed, even using `imgDescriptors` (which is should be not necessary anyway since `cv::Mat1f` should be kinda smart pointer and so deallocate itself at the end of the loop), but I don't understand how's this possible.

This is the `ComputeDescriptor` code for dense SIFT in VLFeat:

```
void DSIFTVLFeat::ComputeDescriptors(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat1f &descriptors){
    descriptors.release();

    // transform image in cv::Mat to float vector
    cv::Mat imgFloat;
    img.convertTo(imgFloat, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);
    if(!imgFloat.isContinuous())
        throw std::runtime_error("imgFloat is not continous");

    for(int i=binSize; i<=maxBinSize; i+=2){
        VlDsiftFilter *dsift = vl_dsift_new_basic (img.rows, img.cols, step, i);
        vl_dsift_process (dsift, imgFloat.ptr<float>());
        cv::Mat scaleDescs(vl_dsift_get_keypoint_num(dsift), 128, CV_32F, (void*) vl_dsift_get_descriptors(dsift));
        descriptors.push_back(scaleDescs);
        scaleDescs.release();
        free(dsift);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out by myself the problem: apparently `free(dsift)` doesn't de-allocate the created descriptors, so I was stacking them on the heap without releasing them.

Calling: `vl_sift_delete(dsift)` instead seems to have solved the problem.